# crystal reports: how to evenly distribute columns

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am using Crystal reports 2013 Support Pack3 version 14.1.3.

I am creating a report which has almost 20 fields. Fields have different sizes. Now I want to evenly distribute the fields so that the spaces between fields are exactly the same size. Does crystal reports have an automatic process to do that or a function (formula) can do that? I have to manually move each field.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to manually move fields

Comment: When you select many and drag them on the report, it distributes evenly, so so much help but atleast a bit.